# Passing arguments to RequestListener Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using `Glide` (version 3) to load images in a `Recyclerview`(onBindViewHolder) with `RequestListener` callback. whenever the image is loaded first time link will get stored in SharedPreferences file with name as`key`. now I want to pass the name into     `RequestListener` as argument. how to pass name as argument into RequestListener? And I also have to pass ImageView so that i can load in onException method in case of loading failure.

Code:

onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactsAdapter.ContactsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final ContactInfo current = cDataset.get(position);
        holder.contactName.setText(current.Contact_name);
        //current.Conatct_name has to be passed to requestListener
        URL url = Util.getSignedUrl(getContext().getApplicationContext(), current.phone_number.concat("/").concat("profile").concat("/").concat(current.phone_number).concat(".jpg"));

        if (url != null) {

            Log.d("image", url.toString());
            Glide.with(getContext()).load(url.toString()).skipMemoryCache(true).fitCenter().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).listener(requestListener).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.contactProfileImage);

        } else {
            Log.d("image", "null");
        }

    }
```

RequestListener:

```
        public RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable> requestListener = new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

             Log.d("No Image",String.valueOf(e));

                Log.d("Loading from cache","true");


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             Log.d("storing cache ","true");

         return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it seems reasonable to create a class, call it `CustomRequestListener` and it implements`RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>` - add a constructor to `CustomRequestListener` which takes the `String key` and the `ImageView`. The `CustomRequestListener` can even be an inner class. Here is a code sample:

```
private class CustomRequestListener implements RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>{ 
//variables to hold the arguments you will be passing to the constructor
private String key;
private ImageView imageView;

//constructor taking the arguments as you desire
public CustomRequestListener(String _key, ImageView defaultImageView){
   this.key = _key;
   this.imageView = defaultImageView
} 

//the rest of your code goes here
@Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

             Log.d("No Image",String.valueOf(e));
             Log.d("Loading from cache","true");
             //you can now load the "default" imageView here...

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
         Log.d("storing cache ","true");
         //here you can save the URL into the SharedPreference - using the "key" variable as its key. Example:
         SharedPreferences prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
         Editor editor = prefs.edit();
         editor.putString(key, theURL);
         editor.apply();

         return false;
        }

};
```

Then to use the custom listener, you do something like this:

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(url.toString()).skipMemoryCache(true).fitCenter().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).listener(new CustomRequestListener (someKey, someImageView)....
```

See [some good examples of using RequestListener](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener)

I hope this helps.